# Laravel yajrabox data table column callback in js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatable

I'm using yajrabox laravel data-table plugin and here is my code.

```
$('#product-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: true,
        order: [[1, 'desc']],
        pageLength: 25,
        ajax: '/filter/custom-json',
        columns: [
                {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "searchable":     false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": '<input type="checkbox">'
            },
            {data: 'title'},
            {data: 'image'},
            {data: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'updated_at'}
        ]
    });
```

In image column, I'm getting an object.So is there any way I can perform some javascript operation before printing it to the table?

Comment: you can specify properties of the object by simply using dot notation: `{data: 'image.property'}`

Comment: I found the solution but again when i return the html element it prints 
[object HTMLImageElement]
instaed of element 

code:https://pastebin.com/WZw5RkCg

Comment: please post a sample of the object.